# difference between two dates with format YYYYMMDDTHHiiss

Tags: php

I have this php code to get the difference between two dates:

```
$date1=date_create("01.06.2021");
$date2=date_create("05.06.2021");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a");
```

Result:

```
+4
```

But how can I realize this, wenn the format of $date1 is for example: 20210605T180000

Comment: Have you tried using the code you already have with `20210605T180000`?

Comment: I agree with @Rocket Hazmat. The code should be working and `date_create` should be parsing it

Comment: I've tested it now , it works just fine?

Comment: okay the problem is that the $date2 should be the today date in this format "20210605T180000". But how ? :/

Comment: @Ghost108 `$date2 = date_create();` will get you the current date/time.

Comment: you are the best ! thanks !! :)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat